# How to change admin user of HTTP Gitolite repository?

Tags: git, gitolite

I have setup a Gitolite repository accessed via HTTP according to directions in http://gitolite.com/gitolite/http.html and https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/t/smart-http.root-setup.
In the latest link, there's a command to setup the respository as

```
HOME=$GITOLITE_HTTP_HOME gitolite setup -a adminusername
```

After creation, I can clone the gitolite-admin.git repository after HTTP authentication as user `adminusername`, and manage it normally. However, I would like to know whether there's a way to change the admin user name form `adminusername`, as repo administration is an employee's role, but if the employee leaves, I would have to transfer it to someone else, and I am not too comfortable with  creating an additional LDAP user to manage the repo (I set up HTTP authentication to use our LDAP server).

Thanks.